# Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (Axios and openweathermap API)

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to render data fetched from openweathermap but I keep getting the following error:

> Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {coord, weather, base, main, visibility, wind, clouds, dt, sys, id, name, cod}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class PersonList extends React.Component {
  state = {
    persons: []
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get(
        `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Toronto&appid=abdeb978cd944502164274a08638f7ac`
      )
      .then(res => {
        const persons = res.data;
        this.setState({ persons });
      });
  }

  render() {
    return <div>{this.state.persons}</div>;
  }
}

export default PersonList;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, transform the json from the response to an object

```
  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Toronto&appid=abdeb978cd944502164274a08638f7ac`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => {
        const persons = res.data;
        this.setState({ persons });
      })
  }
```

Second, `Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {coord, weather, base, main, visibility, wind, clouds, dt, sys, id, name, cod})` means that `{ this.state.persons }` is actualy and object with properties `coord`, `weather`, `base`, `main`, `visibility`, `wind`, `clouds`, `dt`, `sys`, `id`, `name` and `cod`. And you can't render an object.

To see what is in the object, you can do something like

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
         { JSON.stringify(this.state.persons) }
      </div>
    );
  }
```

This will transform the object into a string and you can render a string, so you can see everything that is inside `this.state.persons`.

Now you need to provide us what you want to do with that data, because there is alot of properties to display and alot of things you can do with that.

**Edit:** As said in the comments, to render the `weather`, you can just do

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
         { this.state.persons.weather }
      </div>
    );
  }
```

**But you need to be sure that `weather` is a string**, otherwise, it will cause the same error.

Also, you need to change the inital state of `persons` to an object (maybe you should rename the variable too).

Change this:

```
state = {
    persons: []
}
```

To this:

```
state = {
    persons: {}
}
```

You can also check if `this.state.persons` isn't an empty object, before rendering something from it.

Comment: Thanks! I just want to display the data in "weather". Specifically the description.